# Keep most recent browsing data in web browser

Tags: google-chrome, browser, cache

When you clear your cache in modern browsers you are given choices such as:

- Last hour
- Today
- Last week
- Last month
- All time

Google Chrome on my Android phone has recently started becoming unresponsive when I open it by freezing up and I have to kill it via task manager before I can use it on my Galaxy S10+

I went through and cleared just the "Cached images and files" for "All Time". Now I would like to clear my browsing history as well since it has over 19,000 entries cached across my devices. However, I would prefer to **keep the most recent 4 weeks** of browsing history and delete the rest.

Is there an option for achieving this?

Answer (score 1):

I've not used the feature before myself, but I think your best bet would be through Google's [Takeout](https://takeout.google.com/?pli=1) feature.  If that doesn't capture the specific data you're looking to preserve, I'd look along the lines of an third party utility.